# Showing the full list IDs when OUTER JOIN two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to display not only the overlapped IDs from two tables (table A and table B) but also the unique IDs from two tables?
Here is the example code:

```
SELECT A.ID AS ID
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I think there's something I can do with the `SELECT` line but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you please post a few rows of sample source data along with the desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coalesce()` returns the first non-`null` value from a set of parameters. Is that what you are looking for?

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QYAZV8300

```
create table a (id int) 
insert into a values (1),(3),(5)
create table b (id int) 
insert into b values (2),(3),(4)

select 
    a.id as A_Id
  , b.id as B_Id
  , coalesce(a.id,b.id) as Id
from a
  full join b
    on a.id = b.id
```

returns:

```
+------+------+----+
| A_Id | B_Id | Id |
+------+------+----+
| 1    | NULL |  1 |
| 3    | 3    |  3 |
| 5    | NULL |  5 |
| NULL | 2    |  2 |
| NULL | 4    |  4 |
+------+------+----+
```

Comment: I actually just want to output one ID list combines A IDs and B IDs and my apology for forgetting `FULL` in my sample code.

Comment: @Y.Z. Something like `coalesce(a.id,b.id) as Id` ?